# how to update a file with info from standard input (keyboard) with shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

Basically what I have to do is this:

I have a file containing names of students and their partial grades:

```
(firstname lastname grade)
```

And what I have to do is update that file with their exam grades and their final grades:

```
(partial+exam)/2
```

The exam grades are introduced via the keyboard. So I have to echo a student's name and read his exam grade from the keyboard, and update his line within the file, then move on to the next one, and when I'm all done sort it after the final grade column.

I'm stuck at reading the exam grade from the keyboard. I've tried using some form of `awk` and `sed` but cant get it to work (cant get the info from the keyboard) and I'm not even sure if thats how it has to be done.

Please help.

ty in advance,
bando

edit:
(ty for editing, im a bit new to this)

input looks like this:

```
Tom Green 7
Jenny Patricks 6
Andrew Gibbs 3
Collin Matthews 10
```

it has to run from a script. while running it should put to standard output the first and last name of a student and ask for his grade. once given it edits the file to look like:

```
Tom Green 7 9 8
```

and then steps to the next student.

Comment: Could you provide sample input? Do you want to do it with some script or oneliner?

Comment: i have edited it with sample input. and im trying to write a script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script does something similar you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

# $1 input file
# $2 output file (or equal to $1 if ommitted)

if [ -z "$2" ]; then
    OUTFILE=$1
else
    OUTFILE=$2
fi

cat $1 | while read -u 0 FIRST LAST PART ; do
    echo "firstname: '$FIRST'"
    echo "lastname: '$LAST'"
    echo "grade: '$PART'"
    read -p "Exam grade: " -u 1 EXAM

    #Edit
    # was   let FINAL=(PART+EXAM)/2
    # should be:
    FINAL=$(calc \($PART+$EXAM\)/2)

    echo "$FIRST $LAST $PART $EXAM $FINAL" >> tmp
    echo "final grade: '$FINAL'"
    echo -e "-----------\n"
done

mv tmp $OUTFILE
```

But the shell arithmetic is integer only. For dividing you have two operators: `/` (integer division) and `%` (reminder). I think you should consider other language for the task like `python` or `perl`.

---

**Edit:**
You may want to use the `calc` command from the `apcalc`. See the corrected script above. You'll have to tweak the `calc` command options to prevent it from taking over STDIN. Sorry I have to leave you with that - I have no time right now.

Comment: its my homework in operating systems and we are learning linux programming so i dont really have a choice :( ive got this error message `test.sh: 17: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "done")
`

Comment: ty i will try to sort things out. ty for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

`cat >` will read from keyboard to wherever you like - press ctrl+D to close input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `read` command to get user input from the user in shell script. For example 
`read data 
  echo $data`.

Comment: and how can i use it within awk?

the thing is i have to ask for the grade like this: "<firstname> <lastname>: " and then i need to read the grade, and then have to proccess it before im stepping on to the next person. and i think i have to put this in an awk to edit the line right after reading the grade from the keyboard but i dont know how to achieve this.

Comment: I think the result you need can be achieved using a temp file. That is read the original file, line by line, break each line into three parts, display the first two, and at the same time write it onto the temp file, store the third in a variable, read the input, perform necessary operations, write onto the temp file. After the file is read fully, delete the original file, and rename the temp file to the original file's name.